# What is the difference between a node, stage, and step in Jenkins pipelines?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to understand how to structure my Jenkins 2.7 pipeline groovy script.  I've read through the [pipeline tutorial](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md), but feel that it could expand more on these topics.

I can understand that a pipeline can have many `stage`s and each `stage` can have many `step`s.  But what is the difference between a `step();` and a method call inside a `stage`, say `sh([script: "echo hello"]);`.  Should `node`s be inside or outside of `stage`s?  Should the overall properties of a job be inside or outside a `node`?

Here is my current structure on an ubuntu master node:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

node('master') {
    properties([
        [$class: 'BuildDiscarderProperty', strategy: [$class: 'LogRotator', numToKeepStr: '10']]
    ]);

    stage 'Checkout'
        checkout scm

    stage 'Build'
        sh([script: "make build"]);

    archive("bin/*");
}
```

Answer (score 56):

The concepts of `node`, `stage` and `step` are different:

- `node` specifies *where* something shall happen. You give a name or a label, and Jenkins runs the block there.
- `stage` structures your script into a high-level sequence. Stages show up as columns in the Pipeline Stage view with average stage times and colours for the stage result.
- `step` is one way to specify *what* shall happen. `sh` is of a similar quality, it is a different kind of action. (You can also use `build` for things that are already specified as projects.)

So `step`s can reside within `node`s, (if they don't, they are executed on the master), and `node`s and `step`s can be structured into an overall sequence with `stage`s.

Comment: Was the very last word meant to be `stage`s?

Comment: Steps can no longer reside in nodes, unfortunately. "WorkflowScript: 13: Unknown stage section "node". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a ‘steps’ block"

Answer (score 15):

It depends. Any `node` declaration allocates an executor (on Jenkins master or slave). This requires that you [`stash`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-stash-code-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build) and `unstash` the workspace, as another executor does not have the checked out sources available.

Several steps of the Pipeline DSL run in a flyweight executor and thus do not require to be inside a `node` block.
This might be helpful for an example such as the following, where you need to allocate multiple nodes anyway:

```java
stage("Checkout") {
  checkout scm
}

stage("Build") {
  node('linux') {
    sh "make"
  }
  node('windows') {
    bat "whatever"
  }
}

stage("Upload") {
  ...
```

Another (maybe more realistic example) would be to allocate multiple nodes in `parallel`. Then there's no need to let the `stage` call be executed in another allocated executor (aka within `node`).

Your example looks good to me. There's no need to allocate multiple `node`s within the single `stage`s, as this would be only additional overhead.