# How can I make Jenkins recognize a 'stage' node within a groovy method called from 'steps'?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-blueocean

I have a Jenkins pipeline supported by Groovy in the git SCM which has `stage` inside `steps`.
Why I did it- To reuse the code. Actually our reusable code lies in a groovy method that has got `stage`. And we are calling this groovy method from `steps`. And it is causing the `stage` node to be hidden on blueocean. It is not considering the `stage` as a `stage` just because the stage has been called from `steps`.
Below is how blueocean view looks like. The `Code Push and Test Execution stage` is where the problem lies. The code looks like below-

```
tests = [:]
//code for other stages like Prepare, Initialize, Prepare App
stage('Test') {
            stages{
                stage('Cycle and Test Definition Prep') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                                //groovy code to populate tests variable
                                for (int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_ORGS.toInteger(); ++i) {
                                def orgNumber = i;
                                tests['Org ' + orgNumber] = {
                                    processOrg(orgNumber, cycleKey, definitionKey, newCycleName, folderName)
                                }
                            }
                         }
                    }
                }
                stage('Code Push and Test Execution') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            parallel tests
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

void processOrg(int orgNumber, String testCycleID, String testCycleDefinition, String newCycleName, String testResultFolder) {
    def orgUsername
    def directory

    stage ('Deployment' + orgNumber) {
        //some code
    }
}
```

[image]

I was expecting the stage Deployment 1 etc to show as a stage that does not happen.

PS:- I see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57507753/6532664 & [What is the difference between a node, stage, and step in Jenkins pipelines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549215/what-is-the-difference-between-a-node-stage-and-step-in-jenkins-pipelines) but still want to see if there is a way out. This is working perfectly but just not showing in blueocean and I have downside code to check failure stagees. Now because it is not recognized as a stage so my downside code is not working.

Comment: Or In other words, How can I call a method containing various stages from a stage without using steps block. Currently when I call a method, it asks me to put the call inside steps.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Pipeline Graph View](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-graph-view/) plugin instead of Blue Ocean.

Unfortunately Blue Ocean has problems to render programatically generated nested parallel stages. Blue Ocean is also no more developed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

visual problem occurs because of different logic to render stages in blueocean and classic UI

all code inside of `script {}` will treat as "scripted" pipeline

jenkins classic UI shows "stage name" while blueocean shows branch name

`tests['Org ' + orgNumber]` - its your branch name for parallel [code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/blueocean-plugin/blob/d1fcf4a10a027421cb288d87625f1a354f00fd90/blueocean-pipeline-api-impl/src/main/java/io/jenkins/blueocean/rest/impl/pipeline/PipelineNodeGraphVisitor.java#L493-L506)

in perfect case need to use the same name of stage and name of branch for parallel

```
def tests = [:]

void processOrg(int orgNumber, String testCycleID, String testCycleDefinition, String newCycleName, String testResultFolder) {

    stage ('Deployment' + orgNumber) {
      //some code
    }
}

pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      stages {
        stage('Cycle and Test Definition Prep') {
          steps {
            script {
                //groovy code to populate tests variable
                for (int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_ORGS.toInteger(); ++i) {
                  def orgNumber = i;
                  tests['Deployment' + orgNumber] = {
                    processOrg(orgNumber, cycleKey, definitionKey, newCycleName, folderName)
                  }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        stage('Code Push and Test Execution') {
          steps {
            script {
              parallel tests
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

also would be better to use Map as arg

```
void processOrg(Map args) {
  print("${args.orgNumber} ${args.testCycleID}")
}
```

and use like

```
def args = [orgNumber: 1, testCycleID: "111"]
processOrg(args)
```

or

```
processOrg(orgNumber: 1, testCycleID: "111")
```